# JavaFX - Block user from changing stages without using MODAL

Tags: java, javafx

I have an application that looks like the following:

[image]

When a user clicks on the deck of cards, it opens up a new Stage.

This stage can be closed in one of two ways:

- Right click the stage.
- Click outside of the stage (it has a evenhandler for when it loses focus).

**However**, sometimes I NEED the user to select one or more cards from the deck using this window. I do not want to allow him to close the window until he has selected at least one card. This means I had to use `MODAL` to stop him from being able to access the stage underneath (My Applicaiton). The problem with `MODAL` is now he can never leave the window like he could before by clicking outside the stage, even when I want him to be able to. He is now only able to leave through right clicking. I could add a button but I'd really rather not.

I hope I explained my problem well enough. What would you guys recommend I do? Is there a way I could somehow block the user from going back to the previous stage without `MODAL`? I'm also not able to change `Modality` after the Stage has been shown, so that won't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to use the [onCloseRequestProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#onCloseRequestProperty) property of your pop-up `Stage`.

> Called when there is an external request to close this Window. The
>   installed event handler can prevent window closing by consuming the
>   received event.

With this property you can interrupt the closing of the `Stage` if a condition (in your case at lest one card is selected) is not met by calling [consume](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/event/Event.html#consume--) on the `WindowEvent`.

**Note:** As the documentation states: it is only valid if the **request is external**, so if you call the [close](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#close--) method of the `Stage`, the attached listener will be not executed. As a solution rather than calling this method you can fire the [WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSE_REQUEST](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/WindowEvent.html#WINDOW_CLOSE_REQUEST) event manually.

**Example:**

```
public class PopUpApp extends Application {

    Stage popupStage;
    Stage primaryStage;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
            primaryStage = stage;

            initPopUpStage();

            // When the Pop-Up stage is showing, do not handle any action on the
            // main GUI
            root.disableProperty().bind(popupStage.showingProperty());

            Button b = new Button("Open deck");
            b.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

                    // Add some ToggleButtons to simulate the cards
                    VBox vbox = new VBox();
                    vbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

                    List<ToggleButton> toggles = new ArrayList<ToggleButton>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                        ToggleButton tb = new ToggleButton("Card " + i + 1);
                        toggles.add(tb);
                    }
                    vbox.getChildren().addAll(toggles);

                    Scene sc = new Scene(vbox, 300, 300);
                    popupStage.setScene(sc);

                    // On close request check for the condition
                    popupStage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {

                        @Override
                        public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
                            Boolean readytoClose = false;
                            for (ToggleButton toggle : toggles) {
                                if (toggle.isSelected()) {
                                    readytoClose = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }

                            // Consume the event a show a dialog
                            if (!readytoClose) {
                                event.consume();
                                Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION,
                                        "At least one card has be to be selected!");
                                alert.showAndWait();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    popupStage.show();

                }
            });

            root.setCenter(b);

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void initPopUpStage() {
        popupStage = new Stage();
        popupStage.initOwner(primaryStage);
        popupStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        // On focus loss, close the window
        popupStage.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {

                // Rather than popupStage.close(); fire the event manually
                if (!newValue)
                    popupStage.fireEvent(new WindowEvent(popupStage, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSE_REQUEST));
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Update:**

To make the main `Stage` unavailable I have added this line:

```
root.disableProperty().bind(popupStage.showingProperty());
```

This will disable the root `BorderPane` while the pop-up stage is showing. As soon as the pop-up window closed, the main window is enabled again.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I had no idea I could use onCloseRequest for this kind of functionality. Here's one thing that's a huge problem though. Without `Modality`, the user is still allowed to communicate with the rest of the application despite there being a pop up stage. They could click on the deck 50 times and make 50 windows. My current idea is to have a static boolean variable in my primary GUI class which is says "is a window currently  showing?". If that variable is true, don't allow any event handlers to activate on the primary stage. However that is kind of a pain. Any other ideas?

Comment: Awesome. One last thing. I have six unique windows that will show and hide like this and I would need ALL six of them to bind like that. Right now if I call `.bind()`, it overwrites the previous `bind` and only the last property that was bound properly affects the disabled property. How can I bind multiple?

Comment: You can to it like: `root.disableProperty().bind(popupStage.showingProperty().or(popupStage2.showingProperty()));`